# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while using trigger on computed column

Tags: sql-server-2008

## table

```
create table book_issue_return_details(
issue_id int primary key identity(1,1), 
issued_date date, 
return_date date, 
for_days as datediff(day, return_date, issued_date) persisted, 
penalty int,
payed int, 
balance AS (penalty-payed) PERSISTED);
```

## trigger

```
create trigger trforinsertpenalty
on book_issue_return_details
after insert
as
begin
    declare @value int
    select @value=for_days from book_issue_return_details;
    update book_issue_return_details 
        set penalty=case
        when for_days<'8' then 0
        when for_days='8' then 10
        when for_days='15' then 20
        when for_days='30' then 30 
        when for_days>'30' then 100
        end 
end
```

## insert statement

```
insert into book_issue_return_details(
issued_date,
return_date, 
payed)
values
('16-05-2018','17-05-2018',0),
('07-05-2018','17-05-2018',0),
('01-05-2018','17-05-2018',0),
('17-05-2018','17-05-2018',0),
('01-04-2018','17-05-2018',0);
```

## error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Firstly, complete these basic troubleshooting steps: 1. Only insert one row at a time to see if a particular row triggers it; 2. Disable the trigger to see if the trigger is the issue. This is basic troubleshooting that you should do before asking a question

Comment: You have redundant code in your trigger and it is not even necessary - you can put this calc in a computed column also

Comment: yes , i tried this steps and then asked question

Comment: ...and what did you find? Which of the four inserted rows cause the error? All? Does the trigger make any difference?

Comment: this error is because of date format, i have fixed it after setting dateformat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with  below insert statements..it worked for me.

```
 insert into book_issue_return_details(issued_date,return_date, payed)
 values('16-May-2018','17-May-2018',0),
       ('07-May-2018','17-May-2018',0),
       ('01-May-2018','17-May-2018',0),
       ('17-May-2018','17-May-2018',0),
       ('01-Apr-2018','17-May-2018',0);
```

Comment: Then please mark it as answer. Will help others. Thanks!